# Spring Batch | Job Parameter

Tags: spring-batch, parameter-passing

In case I am passing job parameters, the spring batch job is executed twice, firstly without parameters and then with parameters. I have downloaded many examples from net, the behaviour is same.
Is there a way to call spring batch job just once i.e only with parameters?

Class JobParametersApplication :

```
@EnableBatchProcessing
@SpringBootApplication
public class JobParametersApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    private Job job;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JobParametersApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        
         // Pass the required Job Parameters from here to read it anywhere within Spring Batch infrastructure
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("message", "MyHello").addDate("date", new Date())
                .addLong("time",System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters(); 

        JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
        System.out.println("STATUS :: "+execution.getStatus());
    }
}
```

Class JobConfiguration :

```
@Configuration
public class JobConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public Tasklet helloWorldTasklet(@Value("#{jobParameters['message']}") String message) {
        return (stepContribution, chukContext) -> {
            System.out.println(message);
            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").tasklet(helloWorldTasklet(null)).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job jobParametersJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("jobParametersJob").start(step1()).build();
    }
}
```

Console output :

```
2022-09-03 18:15:43.014  INFO 26884 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner   : Running default command line with: []
2022-09-03 18:15:43.054  INFO 26884 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=jobParametersJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{}]
2022-09-03 18:15:43.069  INFO 26884 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step1]
null
2022-09-03 18:15:43.108  INFO 26884 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=jobParametersJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
2022-09-03 18:15:43.114  INFO 26884 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=jobParametersJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{message=MyHello, date=1662209143110, time=1662209143110}]
2022-09-03 18:15:43.118  INFO 26884 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step1]
MyHello
2022-09-03 18:15:43.124  INFO 26884 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=jobParametersJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{message=MyHello, date=1662209143110, time=1662209143110}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
STATUS :: COMPLETED
2022-09-03 18:15:43.127  INFO 26884 --- [       Thread-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-09-03 18:15:43.129  INFO 26884 --- [       Thread-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following property to your properties or yaml config to prevent automatic execution of jobs

```
spring.batch.job.enabled=false
```